# Data not received back by client via socket [Transport endpoint is already connected]

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, port

I have two programs Node-A and Node-B, where Node-A is sending some char* data to Node-B and Node-B is sending an ack (char* data) to Node-A. ie, the clientNodeA_thread is sending data to Node-B's serverNodeB_thread. The code is as below:

NodeA

```
int main()
    {
      pthread_t clientNodeA, serverNodeA;

      usleep(3000000);
      pthread_create(&clientNodeA, NULL, clientNodeA_thread, "clientNodeA");
      pthread_create(&serverNodeA, NULL, serverNodeA_thread, "serverNodeA");
      usleep(100000000);

      pthread_join(clientNodeA, NULL);
      pthread_join(serverNodeA, NULL);
      return 0;
    }

    void* clientNodeA_thread(void* pString)
    {
        int connSock, in, i, ret, flags;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr, NodeAaddr;
        struct sctp_status status;
        char buffer[MAX_BUFFER+1];
        /* Sample input*/
         strncpy(buffer, "FrmNodeAClt", 12);
         buffer[12]='\0';

         connSock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP );

         if(connSock == -1)
           die("socket()");
         #if 0
         bzero( (void *)&NodeAaddr, sizeof(NodeAaddr) );
         NodeAaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
         NodeAaddr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT_NUM_NodeA2);
         NodeAaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );
         #endif

         bzero( (void *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );
         servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
         servaddr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT_NUM_NodeB);
         servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );



    ret = connect( connSock, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );

         if(ret == -1)
            die("connect()");

           ret = sctp_sendmsg( connSock, (void *)buffer, (size_t)strlen(buffer),
                              NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
        return 0;
    }

    void* serverNodeA_thread(void* pString)
    {
      int listenSock, connSock, ret, in , flags, i;
      struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
      struct sockaddr_in src_addr;
      struct sctp_initmsg initmsg;
      int addr_len = 0;

      listenSock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP );
      bzero( (void *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );
      servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );
      servaddr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT_NUM_ENB2);

  ret = bind( listenSock, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );

      /* Specify that a maximum of 5 streams will be available per socket */
      memset( &initmsg, 0, sizeof(initmsg) );
      initmsg.sinit_num_ostreams = 5;
      initmsg.sinit_max_instreams = 5;
      initmsg.sinit_max_attempts = 4;
      ret = setsockopt( listenSock, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_INITMSG, 
                         &initmsg, sizeof(initmsg) );

      listen( listenSock, 5 );

      while( 1 ) {

      char buffer[MAX_BUFFER + 1];
      int len ;  

      bzero(buffer, MAX_BUFFER + 1);

      printf("Awaiting a new connection\n");

      connSock = accept( listenSock, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, (int *)NULL );
      if(connSock == -1)
          die("accept()");
        else
          printf("New client connected....\n");
          addr_len = sizeof (src_addr);
          recvfrom(connSock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, &src_addr, &addr_len);
          printf("Received data from NodeB : %s\n", (char*)buffer);
      }
    }
```

NodeB

```
int connSock;

/*NodeA context maintenance */
struct NodeAStruct {
  char ipAddr[20];
  unsigned int portNum;
};

static int NodeAInstCount;
struct NodeAStruct NodeAInst[7];

int main()
{

  pthread_t clientNodeA, serverNodeA;

  pthread_create(&serverNodeA, NULL, serverNodeB_thread, "serverNodeA");
  usleep(10000000);

  pthread_join(clientNodeA, NULL);
  pthread_join(serverNodeA, NULL);

  return 0;
}

void* serverNodeB_thread(void* pString)
{
  int listenSock, ret, flags, i;
  struct sockaddr_in src_addr;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  struct sctp_initmsg initmsg;
  struct sctp_event_subscribe events;
  struct sctp_sndrcvinfo sndrcvinfo;
  char sendBuffer[MAX_BUFFER+1];
  unsigned int NodeA_PORT_NUM;
  char* NodeA_IP_ADDR;  
  char  from_ip[1024] = "", myip[2014] = "";
  int addr_len = 0;

  listenSock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP ); 
  bzero( (void *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );
  //servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl("127.0.0.1");
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT_NUM_NodeB);

  ret = bind( listenSock, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );

  /* Specify that a maximum of 5 streams will be available per socket */
  memset( &initmsg, 0, sizeof(initmsg) );
  initmsg.sinit_num_ostreams = 5;
  initmsg.sinit_max_instreams = 5;
  initmsg.sinit_max_attempts = 4;
  ret = setsockopt( listenSock, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_INITMSG, 
                     &initmsg, sizeof(initmsg) );

  listen( listenSock, 5 );

  while( 1 ) {

  char buffer[MAX_BUFFER + 1];
  int len ;  

  bzero(buffer, MAX_BUFFER + 1);
  printf("Awaiting a new connection\n");

  connSock = accept( listenSock, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, (int *)NULL );
  if(connSock == -1)
      die("accept()");
    else
    {
      printf("New client connected....\n");     
      addr_len = sizeof (src_addr);
      recvfrom(connSock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, &src_addr, &addr_len);

      printf("Received message: %s from NodeA IP: %s Port: %u  \n", (char*)buffer, inet_ntop(AF_INET, &src_addr.sin_addr, from_ip, sizeof(from_ip)), ntohs(src_addr.sin_port));
      strcpy(NodeAInst[NodeAInstCount].ipAddr, inet_ntop(AF_INET, &src_addr.sin_addr, from_ip, sizeof(from_ip)));
      NodeAInst[NodeAInstCount].portNum = ntohs(src_addr.sin_port);
      printf("NodeA instance [%d] added \n", NodeAInstCount);

     /* Send data to NodeA*/
     strncpy(sendBuffer, "From NodeB", 12);
     sendBuffer[12]='\0';
     NodeA_PORT_NUM = NodeAInst[NodeAInstCount].portNum;
     usleep(10000000);
     ret = sctp_sendmsg( connSock, (void *)sendBuffer, (size_t)strlen(sendBuffer),
                          NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
     if(ret>0) {
        printf("Data sent to NodeA \n");
     }
     else {
        printf("Sending data to NodeA failed");
     }
     usleep(6000000);
     NodeAInstCount++;

    }
  }
}
```

I am able to send data from Node-A client to Node-B server, and the Node-B is also able to send Ack data (as verified in Wireshark), but it is not reaching Node-A receive code.

Any help in this regard would be highly helpful.

Comment: You don't need that big `usleep` after thread creation, `pthread_join` will block until the thread it joins exits.

Comment: By the way, in the `clientNodeA_thread` function you copy a string of 11 characters (plus terminator) into `buffer` then you add the terminator at position 13, remember that indexes are zero-based. Not that it matters, since you copy enough from the source string that `strncpy` will add the terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you bind the client A socket to the local address, but you don't bind the passive server socket.

Don't bind client sockets, there's often no need for that. You *do* need to bind the server sockets locally though, or the system will just bind it to a random port when you call `listen`.

Comment: I am binding the clientA socket because I want to decode them at Node-B server... I am using the loopback address and a specific port number to bind the client A. Idk, could you please elaborate a bit on what you think is the issue here? Thanks a lot..

Comment: Were you mentioning that I didn't use bind at Node-A's server thread? I am not very sure, but do we have to use bind twice? As I just use one port number to listen? Wouldn't I get unable to bind error if I do so?

Comment: @user5105767 But you bind the *client* socket to a local address, that's not needed as it will get a locally bound address when you `connect`. The server socket *needs* to be bound to a fixed local address, or otherwise the clients won't know what address to connect to. I recommend you read the [**NOTES** section in this `listen` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html#NOTES), it tells you what you need to do for a server socket.

Comment: @user5105767 Where in `serverNodeA_thread` do you call `bind` with `listenSock`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have modified the serverNodeA thread with bind and listenSock. Looks like the Node-A server is still unable to detect any incoming packets. I have updated the original post with the code I am using now. I have also removed the bind and listenSock in clientNodeAthread.. Could you see anything wrong now? I am new to the sockets, and hey, thanks for the link!

Comment: Updated the original code properly in the first post. Guess I am doing it the right way now - as per the man pages. Binding in the server thread with loopback address. Anything more comes to your notice now? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hmm.. And also if I don't do bind at NodeA client thread, I guess the NodeA would use any random port number to send the data, which I guess I would avoid..

Comment: @user5105767 Client socket you seldom need to bind, the random port number is alright. If you use connectionless protocols like UDP you need to bind to a local port, but not when using connection-oriented protocols.

Comment: I get it.. Do you, by chance see anthing else which I am doing wrong so that the data from NodeB send function is not reaching NodeA's server thread? Guess the socket related set-up is correct now and also I am sending data from NodeB to port which I have used for binding at NodeA server..

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved! I just moved the NodeA's socket creation and bind part to the main function so that it would be shared by both client and server threads, and the client and server threads would just do the send and receive functionality.

Thanks @Joachim Pileborg